# HawkBit SWUpdate Auto Connect

Tags: eclipse-hawkbit

In the combination of HawkBit-Server and SWUpdate-Client is it possible to give SWU the Server-IP without any security token, so that it can connect to the Server and create a new device and is provided a token by the server. So that i don't have to create a new device and put the Security Token inside SWUpdate's config manually all the time?

Kind Regards